# Object not defined when running in a loop, but not when executed sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I'm using the [jQuery Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to set all input elements with a data-mask attribute defined to the attribute mask value:

Given this html:

```
<input type='text' id="a" data-mask='999?999' />
<input type='text' id="b" data-mask='999' />
```

And this script:

```
$("input[data-mask]").each(function() {

    var maskValue = $(this).data('mask');

    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ": " + maskValue);

    //undefined error here on second iteration "b: 999"
    //no issues if you remove the data-mask from one of the input elements
    return $(this).mask(maskValue);

});
```

The second iteration an error is thrown: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on this line, saying 'split' is not defined.

```
firstNonMaskPos = null, $.each(mask.split(""), function(i, c) {
```

This code however works just fine, the masks are set with no issue.

```
$('#a').mask('999?999');
$('#b').mask('999');
```

Could anyone shine any light on this odd behavior?

[Demo jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/oj4pt642/3/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second one is being typed as `number` by `data()`

Since split() is a string method it is throwing error.

Simple fix:

```
var maskValue = "" + $(this).data('mask');
```

or

```
 var maskValue =  $(this).data('mask').toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.data('mask')` with `.attr('data-mask')`. Works fine now for me for some reason... Maybe jQuery version related?